# Shiny doesn't renderText() for a formula correctly, puts ~ at the beginning

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to renderText() some input to a formula. I want the user to select the input `Y` variable but the `X` variables are held fixed. When I run the code in RStudio, everything works fine, but when I try to see what `formula` is created I see that I have something wrong... i.e. I have `~ relative_excess Periodo` where it should be: `relative_excess ~ Periodo`

Screenshot of error:

[image]

App:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Formula not showing correctly"),
    
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
      inputId = "var_to_forecast_CF1",
      label = h4("Variable To Predict"),
      choices = c("Total_Deaths", "relative_excess"),
      selected = "Total_Deaths"
    ),
    
    
    verbatimTextOutput("formula_to_estimate_1")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  formula_to_estimate = reactive({
    #formula(paste0(input$var_to_forecast_CF1,  "~Periodo", sep = ""))
    paste0(input$var_to_forecast_CF1, "~", "Periodo") %>% 
      as.formula()
  })
  
  output$formula_to_estimate_1 = renderText({
    print(paste(formula_to_estimate()))
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` is the wrong way to convert an object to a string. The right way is either `as.character` (which is implicitly called by `paste`) or, in the case of language objects, `deparse`.

Since formulas are language objects in R, use `deparse`.

Furthermore, as Stéphane wrote, the `print` call is unnecessary here. This leaves us with:

```
output$formula_to_estimate_1 = renderText({
  deparse(formula_to_estimate())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work if you don't apply `as.formula`. And you don't have to use `print` in `renderText`.

Comment: If I do not apply `as.formula` will I have problems later on when I pass the pasted command to some regression model?

Comment: @user113156 Yes, but you can apply `as.formula` later, when you need it.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent But OP *wants* to output the formula. The issue is that the `paste()` call inside `renderText()` mis-formats the formula. *This* needs to be removed/replaced (e.g. by `deparse()`).